# Override NSUserDefault preferences at build time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, plist, nsuserdefaults

I would like to be able to set app preferences at build time in my iOS project.  I know that I can create different targets in xcode but I think with the amount of preferences I might end of making I could end up with a nightmarish amount of targets in my project.

An easy example is setting the a default integer for a default called 'amount'.  Currently 'amount' is defined in a plist file in my app called 'preferences.plist'.  I load that plist file and register defaults with that plist on NSUserDefaults.

```
NSURL *preferencesFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"preferences" withExtension:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *defaultPreferences = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:defaultPreferencesFile];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  registerDefaults:preferences];
```

I assume I could write a script to modify the preferences.plist file before I build, then build it.  However I think might become a nightmare when I need to mod a bunch of different preferences.

End game is to have jenkins build my IPAs.  I would like to easily create multiple jenkins builds that will point to the same code based but build my app with different preferences.

Android has flavors, and the ability to set resource values.  Does iOS have a something similar that I can use to build these different 'flavors' of apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a Jenkins build action to inject the appropriate variables into the plist before the Xcode build:

```
plutil -replace MyBuildBranch -string ${BRANCH} MyProj/MyProj-Info.plist
```

I then read that value at runtime using something like:

```
NSBundle * bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[AppDelegate class]];
NSString * myBuildBranch = bundle.infoDictionary[@"MyBuildBranch"]
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about plutil.  That sounds perfect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough working experience with Android.

I'd approach this with multiple plists.. One for each flavor..

And i'll try either of the below options --

1. I'd have Jenkins swap the plist based on the flavor i am trying to build.. the script will pick the right plist for a given flavor
2. I will define compile-time MACROS for each flavor and load the appropriate plist.. something like this

   ```
   #ifdef FLAVOUR1
       NSURL *preferencesFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"preferences-flavour1" withExtension:@"plist"];
       NSDictionary *defaultPreferences = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:defaultPreferencesFile];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  registerDefaults:preferences];
   #endif
   #ifdef FLAVOUR2
       NSURL *preferencesFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"preferences-flavour2" withExtension:@"plist"];
       NSDictionary *defaultPreferences = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:defaultPreferencesFile];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  registerDefaults:preferences];
   #endif
   #ifdef FLAVOUR2
       NSURL *preferencesFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"preferences-flavour3" withExtension:@"plist"];
       NSDictionary *defaultPreferences = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:defaultPreferencesFile];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  registerDefaults:preferences];
   #endif
   ```